# Prop does not change from true to false in react, redux, node app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, react-redux

As the title says, I have a check in `RegistrationForm` for checking if user email exists in the database. The prop is `userExists`. Now, if it's true, that means **User email exists**, so the user should be shown a message that says- "User already exists." Now, if it's false, he should be successfully registered and redirected to login.

But right now, I cannot even register with any email. In the network tab, it returns a 200 and gives
the response:
`{"message":"User with this email does not exist"}`

Can someone show me the proper way to do it? I mean the check, and the message from the backend, through redux, and back to the component.

My code is jibberish.

`RegistrationForm` Component

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { registerUser, checkValidUser } from "../../actions/userActions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import validator from "validator";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { toastError } from "../../../utils/toastify";

class RegistrationForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { username, email, password } = this.state;

    const registrationData = {
      username: this.state.username,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    };

    if (!username || !email || !password) {
      return toastError("Credentials should not be empty");
    }

    if (username.length < 6) {
      return toastError("Username should be greater than 6 characters.");
    }

    if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
      return toastError("Invalid email.");
    }

    if (password.length < 6) {
      return toastError("Password must contain 6 characters.");
    }

    await this.props.dispatch(checkUserExists(email));

    const userExists = this.props.userExists;

    if (!userExists) {
      this.props.dispatch(
        registerUser(registrationData, () => {
          this.props.history.push("/login");
        })
      );
    } else {
      toastError("User with this email already exisits"); // I'm not sure how to show the message if the user email already exists. I want to show the message from backend, but currently I'm just doing it manually
    }
  };

  render() {
    const isRegistrationInProgress = this.props.isRegistrationInProgress;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
            <input
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="username"
              value={this.state.username}
              className="input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Username"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left has-icons-right">
            <input
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              className="input"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Email"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <p className="control has-icons-left">
            <input
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              name="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              className="input"
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
            <span className="icon is-small is-left">
              <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="field">
          <div className="control">
            {isRegistrationInProgress ? (
              <button className="button is-success is-loading">Sign Up</button>
            ) : (
              <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="button is-success">
                Sign up    console.log("registrationData", registrationData)

              </button>
            )}
            <Link to="/login">
              <p className="has-text-danger">
                Already have an account? Sign In
              </p>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isRegistrationInProgress: state.registration.isRegistrationInProgress,
    userExists: state.registration.userExists,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RegistrationForm);
```

`checkUserExists` action

```js
export const checkUserExists = (email) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/users/checkUserExists/${email}`)
        console.log("res=>", res)
        if (res.data.message = "User with this email already exists") {
          dispatch({
            type: "CHECK_USER_EXISTS_SUCCESS",  
          })
        }
      } catch (err) { 
        console.log("error=>", err)
      }
    }
  }
```

`checkUserExists` controller function

```js
checkUserExists: async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email } = req.params
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email })
    if (user) {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "User with this email already exists" })
    } else {
      return res.json({ message: "User with this email does not exist" })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error)
  }
}
```

`registerUser` action

```js
export const registerUser = (registrationData, redirect) => {
   return async (dispatch) => {
     dispatch({ type: "REGISTRATION_STARTS" })
     try {
       const res = await axios.post(
         `${baseUrl}/users/register`,
         registrationData
       )
       dispatch({
         type: "REGISTRATION_SUCCESS",
         data: { user: res.data.user },
       })
       toastSuccess("Successfully registered")
       redirect()
     } catch (err) {
       dispatch({
         type: "REGISTRATION_ERROR",
         data: { error: err },
       })
     }
   }
 }
```

`registration` reducer

```js
const initialState = () => ({
  isRegistrationInProgress: false,
  isRegistered: false,
  registrationError: null,
  user: {},
  userExists: false,
  error: null,
});

const registration = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "REGISTRATION_STARTS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isRegistrationInProgress: true,
        registrationError: null,
      };

    case "REGISTRATION_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        isRegistrationInProgress: false,
        registrationError: null,
        isRegistered: true,
        user: action.data,
      };

    case "REGISTRATION_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        isRegistrationInProgress: false,
        registrationError: action.data.error,
        isRegistered: false,
        user: {},
      };
    case "CHECK_USER_EXISTS_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...state,
        userExists: true,
        error: null
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default registration;
```

Comment: You don't appear to be doing any sort of typeahead validation for the username, so why bother checking if the user exists before you try register? Just do it as part of the registration. Also, I'd advise you make better use of HTTP status codes for your result checking i.e. `if (res.statusCode === 404) { // user does not exist }` as opposed to `res.data.message` (messages may change, status codes won't)

Comment: No, I'm checking for the email not the username.

Comment: Doesn't matter, point still stands